# Remove a setting from the settings screen in iOS on app upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, settings-bundle

My app initially used a feature that required microphone access. So the settings screen used to show the toggle switch for toggling that permission on or off. In the new version we no longer need that feature. So I removed the entry for microphone from the Root.plist in the Settings.bundle. This works for new installations. But for a user updating the app, the settings still shows the microphone permission. Is there any way to remove that entry ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to delete the `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` key from your info.plist file. I guess that as long as iOS sees that key, it will render the corresponding entry in your app's settings.

You can read more about what this key does [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios).

Comment: I did indeed remove the key from info.plist as part of removing the functionality. Sorry i forgot to mention that. But as mentioned, while the settings look as expected for a new installation, for app upgrades, the toggle switch for microphone is still shown. I suspect that is because even though new users won't be asked for the permission, there is no way of undoing the permission granting process via code for upgrading users.

Comment: Right, that makes sense - good thinking. You should post it as a reply!